# Only 1 result is being displayed

Tags: java

I have this problem for homework and the issue I'm having is when I run the program and input the values I only get one result 
for instance if I enter 30 for the number of years I get this "30   14730.576123040439" 30 times. Any ideas of what I can do to get the proper results to display(ie years 1-30 instead of just the correct result for year 30 30 times).

```
   public class FinancialApp57 
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           //variables
           double intRate, invAmt;
           int yrs;
           String inv = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an investment amount:");
           invAmt = Double.parseDouble(inv);
           String rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an intrest rate: ");
           intRate = Double.parseDouble(rate);
           String yr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                   ("Enter the lenght of investment(in years): ");
           yrs = Integer.parseInt(yr);

           futureInvestmentValue(invAmt,intRate/12,yrs);
       }

       public static double futureInvestmentValue
               (double investmentAmount,double monthlyIntrestRate,int years)
       {
           double FutureValue = 0;
           int i = 1;
           FutureValue=
                   investmentAmount*Math.pow((1+monthlyIntrestRate/100),years*12);

           while(i<years)
           {            
               System.out.println(years+"\t" + FutureValue);
               i++;
           }
           return FutureValue;

       }
   }
```

Comment: This is what a debugger can be extremely useful for. Someone has provided you the answer, but stepping through your code likely would have shown you your mistake as well. Next time, try to solve the problem yourself. As others have said, that's the purpose of homework. What do you learn by getting answers from others?

Comment: @AEFXX My program is COMPLETE and I'm not asking anyone to do it for me. I had a simple question on what I was missing, if you are not going to help don't bother posting. Not to mention that if I hadn't done anything on my own how would I even know what I WANT TO ASK ABOUT! WHY ARE HELP FORUMS SO FULL OF JERKS!?

Comment: @Mikezx6r I saw, I tried it and seems like I'm still getting the same thing 30 of the same (last) answer. Also, I have been working on this myself and I only ask for help when I have exhausted everything I can think of. isn't that the point of HELP FORUMS!

Comment: @JohnDziendziel - SO isn't a "help forum" in the traditional sense. The guidelines are pretty clear on what constitutes a question here. Yours ... wasn't; "What's wrong with my code?" isn't a valid question on SO - it falls under "too localized" which is a reason to close the question.

Comment: I guess I was thinking that if you debugged it, you would see what others have kindly pointed out. FutureValue is computed once, outside your loop, and therefore in the while, FutureValue is always the same. You may have also noticed that you were printing years rather than i in the println. Maybe not... It's always easier to look at someone else's code and see 'simple things'. I know what it's like to not see something, have someone else look at it and say 'oh, you're missing a {very small thing} here'... Apologies for sounding harsher than I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value your code prints is "years", when you enter '30', then int years = 30, if you want something like (1,2,3,4,5....), you should print "i" instead of "years", so must be:

```
while(i<=years) {            
    System.out.println(i+"\t" + FutureValue);
    i++;
}
return FutureValue;
```

Comment: After I used your suggestion, my room mate pointed out to me that I also needed to have i in another place and that was why I was getting the same 30 results. Honestly I have been working on this for so long that I just couldn't see what the problem was. Thanks for your help. I wish more people were more helpful like this.

Answer (score 2):

Your not recalculating the FutureValue 30 times, you're only calculating it once, then printing it 30 times.  Put the calculation for FutureValue in the loop and adjust its parameters accordingly